# Bar plot colour depending on conditional value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm trying to colour my bar plot of students grades, depending on if they passed a certain exam or not.

To do this I read in two separate .csv files and structured the data so it's ordered by a certain variable. Here's the head of one of the datasets:

```
 head(Y)
  fName mid lab exam overall
1 OOJOE  50  94 77.5      77
2 JWTWB  45  50 60.5      54
3 XQXQA  65  78 69.0      71
4 PVTMX  35  84 30.5      47
5 ZZBDP  70 100 74.0      81
6 JVYMA  65  96 73.5      79
```

The other data set (X) contains info about student attendance etc. 
I made a boxplot for each student, showing the median attendance (using dataset X) but my overall goal is to colour the boxplots depending on whether each student got an overall grade of 40 or above (which is from data set Y).

I'm using ggplot... Here's what I've tried so far:

```
ggplot(data=X,aes(x=fName, y=delay, group=fName)) + 
  geom_boxplot(color = Y$overall <40) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'overall < 40', values = setNames(c('red','green'),c(T, F))) + 
  coord_flip()
```

But this just tells me that it's an invalid colour name... I also tried:

```
ggplot(data=X,aes(x=fName, y=delay, group=fName)) + 
  geom_boxplot(color =  ifelse(Y$overall >= 40,'red','green')) +
  coord_flip()
```

This does separate the boxplots into two different colours... but it's not doing it correctly (i.e., it's not colouring the values >= 40 red and all the others green... it just seems to be randomly assigning some students red and some green). I suspect it's not working because of the `ifelse` command not working well with `ggplot`, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions as to how I'd fix this?

EDIT:
Here's the head of X, just to show an example of the delay column:

```
head(X)
  fName    Information                fTime            min.Time.     delay
1 ARONR Course outline 2010-09-22T09:16:00Z 2010-09-20T20:21:00Z 1.5381944
2 ARONR    Lab  Dec 13 2010-12-11T17:21:00Z 2010-12-09T12:20:00Z 2.2090278
3 ARONR      Lab Nov 1 2010-11-03T11:10:00Z 2010-10-28T17:21:00Z 5.7423611
4 ARONR     Lab Nov 22 2010-11-22T14:16:00Z 2010-11-22T11:51:00Z 0.1006944
5 ARONR     Lab Nov 29 2010-11-29T15:04:00Z 2010-11-25T18:00:00Z 3.8777778
6 ARONR      Lab Nov 8 2010-11-10T11:07:00Z 2010-11-05T19:12:00Z 4.6631944
```

Here's some additional data concerning only one student to help merging under common key:
Y-data set:

```
fName mid lab exam overall
ZZBDP  70 100 74.0      81
```

X-data set:

```
fName    Information                fTime            min.Time.     delay
ZZBDP  Lecture Dec 1 2010-12-01T13:02:00Z 2010-12-01T12:31:00Z 2.152778e-02                 ZZBDP  Lecture Dec 8 2010-12-08T08:49:00Z 2010-12-07T16:43:00Z 6.708333e-01
ZZBDP Lecture Nov 10 2010-11-10T11:14:00Z 2010-11-09T13:35:00Z 9.020833e-01
ZZBDP Lecture Nov 17 2010-11-17T18:25:00Z 2010-11-17T10:31:00Z 3.291667e-01
ZZBDP Lecture Nov 24 2010-11-24T09:23:00Z 2010-11-23T11:35:00Z 9.083333e-01
```

Comment: What is `delay`? It is not in your data.frame

Comment: delay is a variable from the X-dataset. It a floating point number (eg: 1.5381944), which is a measure of how long a student took to access online material... The boxplots for this particular question show the median delay for each student (rather than attendance as mentioned above)

Answer (score 1):

By converting the updated `X` and `Y` data.frames to data.tables and then merging them on `fName` I get the following `data.table` (`dt`):

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
X <- structure(list(fName = c("ZZBDP", "ZZBDP", "ZZBDP", "ZZBDP", 
      "ZZBDP"), Information = c("Lecture Dec 1", "Lecture Dec 8", "Lecture Nov 10", 
      "Lecture Nov 17", "Lecture Nov 24"), fTime = c("2010-12-01T13:02:00Z", 
      "2010-12-08T08:49:00Z", "2010-11-10T11:14:00Z", "2010-11-17T18:25:00Z", 
      "2010-11-24T09:23:00Z"), min.Time. = c("2010-12-01T12:31:00Z", 
      "2010-12-07T16:43:00Z", "2010-11-09T13:35:00Z", "2010-11-17T10:31:00Z", 
      "2010-11-23T11:35:00Z"), delay = c(0.0215, 0.671, 0.902, 0.329, 
      0.908)), .Names = c("fName", "Information", "fTime", "min.Time.", 
      "delay"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")  

Y <- structure(list(fName = c("OOJOE", "JWTWB", "XQXQA", "PVTMX", 
      "ZZBDP", "JVYMA"), mid = c(50L, 45L, 65L, 35L, 70L, 65L), lab = c(94L, 
      50L, 78L, 84L, 100L, 96L), exam = c(77.5, 60.5, 69, 30.5, 74, 
      73.5), overall = c(77L, 54L, 71L, 47L, 81L, 79L)), .Names = c("fName", 
      "mid", "lab", "exam", "overall"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")  

# Convert to data.table
setDT(X)
setDT(Y)

# Merge X and Y on fName and store in dt
dt <- Y[X, on="fName"]

>dt
   fName mid lab exam overall    Information                fTime            min.Time.  delay
1: ZZBDP  70 100   74      81  Lecture Dec 1 2010-12-01T13:02:00Z 2010-12-01T12:31:00Z 0.0215
2: ZZBDP  70 100   74      81  Lecture Dec 8 2010-12-08T08:49:00Z 2010-12-07T16:43:00Z 0.6710
3: ZZBDP  70 100   74      81 Lecture Nov 10 2010-11-10T11:14:00Z 2010-11-09T13:35:00Z 0.9020
4: ZZBDP  70 100   74      81 Lecture Nov 17 2010-11-17T18:25:00Z 2010-11-17T10:31:00Z 0.3290
5: ZZBDP  70 100   74      81 Lecture Nov 24 2010-11-24T09:23:00Z 2010-11-23T11:35:00Z 0.9080
```

The above data.table contains both the independent variable (`fName`), the dependent variable (`delay`), and the variable to use for colouring (`overall`).

To make a boxplot of `delay` vs `fName` with `overall` scores greater than or equal to 40 being colored red (and those below 40 colored green), use:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = fName, y = delay, group = fName, color = overall >= 40)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green")) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help... but this is the issue I'm having... I'm reading in two separate .csv files (which I've called X & Y). The data set X contains the variable delay whereas the data set Y has the variable overall. I've edited the main question to show the head of X. Would you suggest that I join the delay column from X to the data set Y and use gglplot, or is there another way?

Comment: OK, I would then use data.table to merge X and Y using a common key (fName?) and then plot the merged data. Your examples of X and Y do not contain a common key so I cannot really provide an example. If you want help with this provide X and Y data on the same person.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the main question to provide some data on a single student... Thanks for all your help... I'm not exactly sure how to merge using a common key.